In Haskell on Linux, is there a way of emitting an executable file for an arbitrary IO action?
I'm looking for a function like this:
writeExecutable :: FilePath -> IO () -> IO ()

This would create an executable Linux binary file that, when run, would do the provided IO action as if it were the main function of a Haskell program.
It seems like this sort of thing would be (1) possible in principle, and (2) very useful. Has there been any work in this area?
eta. The idea is that if a program were to call writeExecutable fname action and then UNIX exec on fname, it would be equivalent to running action and then exiting.

Did you mean serialization an arbitrary IO action? If so, your question should be about the existence of a function with the following signature IO () -> ByteString.

What would fix (writeExecutable "foo") do? :P

fix (writeExecutable "foo") would create an executable file that, when run, would create an executable file that did the same thing. Basically a binary quine.

Perhaps Cloud Haskell is relevant/useful for whatever you're actually trying to do.

It is impossible for generic scenario.
Only way to actually do it is to save all state of current process and restore it in new one.
Imagine your process have opened tcp connection and logged in into some remote system. How do you recreate that situation?

In that case, running the program would attempt to read from a TCP connection as if it had been opened.

So I believe it is possible and this answer is incorrect.

Imagine the tcp connection starts an ssh session. Would it also resend the bytes necessary to log in or would it just start reading/writing from a fresh socket? What would you do if the connection involves a randomized cryptographic protocol (so you can't just replay it)?

It would just start reading/writing from the same socket. The session would then fail in this case, because the program you have created assumes an SSH session has already been opened.

@AshleyYakeley it will fail because remote side will expect login. If you OK with failure, then writing such a program is trivial.

Yes, of course it would fail. writeExecutable is doing exactly what you asked it to do, which is to output a program that does a thing. If that thing has an expectation that isn't met, then it will fail.

@AshleyYakeley So you just need a program that always fail? Technically we can do "best effort" approach. It still will have little to none practical application. Such system will be extremly difficult to maintain, It will be unpredictable, In any possible scenario I kan see there is better solution.

If you write out an executable file that uses a TCP socket that has already been allocated, then obviously it should fail when run, because it won't reallocate the TCP socket. I'm not sure why you are focussing on this particular case?

@AshleyYakeley because it's not a 'particular' case. Virtually all 'useful' applications of such an idea would involve setting up some state first and attempting to reuse it. If you don't need any prior state, that's just the main function.

I just want a function that writes an executable file for an IO action. I don't see the point of coming up with examples where that executable file will (correctly!) fail when run.

@AshleyYakeley We assumed that generated executable should behave exactly as if supplied IO is executed inplace. So we tried to explain that is impossible. If that assumption is wrong please explain what behavior expected from generated executable?

OK, I see what you're saying: there's no way to record an open TCP socket into an executable file in a way that survives UNIX exec, is that correct?

@AshleyYakeley Yes. And it is only one example. Are you asking this question for practical reason or just from quriosity?

If you were to hard-code the pointer to the open TCP socket into the file, and assuming exec doesn't interfere with the open socket, then executing the file should be the same as running in-place. Of course, if one were to execute the file at some later time, it would (correctly) fail.

I'm not sur that you can use pointer to socket from another process. It will be major security breach.

It's the same process, though. UNIX exec keeps the same process but replaces the running code.

Aside from the problem of captured resources discussed in the other answer, printing the code of a function would be quite against the spirit of Haskell because it breaks equational reasoning. We like to be able to write an equation like 1 + 1 == 2 and be safe in the belief that the two expressions are undistinguishable: f (1 + 1) behaves as f 2 for any f. (Otherwise, what do you think 1 + 1 == 2 should mean?)
What happens to f x = writeExecutable "a" (print x)? Would f (1 + 1) print print (1 + 1) or print 2? An even worse situation is f k = writeExecutable "a" (readLine >>= k), as finding a unique representation for a function is an uncomputable problem.

Both f (1 + 1) and f 2 would output a binary file that, when run, would print 2. I'm not seeing any breaking of referential transparency here. Also I don't see any problem with f k = writeExecutable "a" (readLine >>= k). You have to pass it some k before it outputs an executable file.

The question is whether the binary file produced by f (1 + 1) would be the same as f 2. Either you introduce an observable distinction between (1 + 1) and 2, or you try to hide it. You find a unique representation (which is not possible if you replace numbers with functions), or you ignore the distinction (maybe you don't see a problem with it but you can't argue everybody else would be fine if you just told them they can't arbitrarily inspect a file they just wrote).

OK, if you're going to peer into the binary file, I guess that would count as breaking referential transparency within the IO monad. I'm OK with that. writeExecutable is going to make use of low-level runtime functions in any case.

Breaking referential transparency is a concern, but I believe it's not a huge deal if done  inside IO. I'd argue that IO is already breaking referential transparency. In IO we can observe how long it takes for an expression to be evaluated and how much memory it's being consumed. We can even call FFI, or open /proc/self/exe and read the machine code. I guess we could even attach a debugger to the current process and read from its memory. Serializing an IO action (inside IO) does not seem to be much worse to me.

MicroHS can do that.
See cprint incInt here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zk5SJ79nOnA&t=2432s

I believe your question is about something else, namely the existence of a species function:
codeIO :: IO () -> ByteString

If such a function existed, then it would be possible to implement yours, like this:
writeExecutable pth action = do
    ByteString.writeFile pth $ codeIO action
    perm <- getPermissions pth
    setPermissions pth $ setOwnerExecutable True perm


The main problem with the existence of the codeIO function is the possibility of obtaining a code for an arbitrary function. The standard does not require the existence of such a possibility, which gives a wide space in the implementation of the compiler. Therefore, I am sure that such a possibility does not exist.

Another reason is that some objects cannot be serialized, for example Handle.
main = do
    writeFile "foo" "content"
    h <- openFile "foo" ReadMode
    writeExecutable "bar" (putStr =<< hGetContents h)

h cannot be saved and restored when bar is executed because there is no information about how it was created. It could have been created with a lot of side effects.

Sure, implementing writeExecutable would require low-level access to the GHC runtime system. But it could still be done.

@AshleyYakeley It could be and exists - these are different statuses. As I known, GHC does not support this feature.

As I asked in the OP, has there been any work in this area?

@AshleyYakeley I believe that no one worked on it, for the reason indicated by talex.

Personally, I'd be strongly against codeIO :: IO () -> ByteString, but OK with codeIO :: IO () -> IO ByteString. Since serialization will almost invariably break referential transparency, it should only be allowed inside IO.

@chi I look at it this way. Let's imagine that the GHC compiles only into the lambda calculation, and the runtime works simply as an interpreter of this lambda calculation. In this case, maybe, it is possible to get a lambda representation for any term. That is, x :: IO () is just a lambda term that codeIO x simply serializes.
